# Spring Boot and Log4j Issue

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, log4j

my log4j setup is following. When I run as Boot App, the logs are correctly written in console, debug.log and dump.log. Below is what I do in my program to write log in console and debug.log

```
static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EnvironmentLoader.class);    
LOG.info("blah blah!");
```

Below is what I do in my program to write log in dump.log

```
private static final Logger DUMP_LOG = Logger.getLogger("dumpLogger");
DUMP_LOG.info("blah blah!");
```

Both works fine if I run as Spring Boot App. If I package it as war and run in tomcat, `DUMP_LOG` writes correctly in dump.log but `LOG` is not writing in console or debug.log. I wonder why.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, debugLog

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.debugLog.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=${catalina.base}/logs/debug.log
log4j.appender.debugLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.debugLog.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.debugLogger=DEBUG, debugLog
log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false

log4j.appender.dumpLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dumpLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.dumpLog.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.dumpLog.File=${catalina.base}/logs/dump.log
log4j.appender.dumpLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.dumpLog.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.dumpLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dumpLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n

log4j.category.dumpLogger=DEBUG, dumpLog
log4j.additivity.dumpLogger=false
```

Answer (score 0):

The following dependency resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great..!! Mohan. I hope this will help me a lot to save my time. thank you.